# How to display duplicate column as a separated column while converting text to csv using sed commnad?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, sed, tr

**Problem Statement :**

Used sed commands to convert text to csv. But it contains some columns with same name, so sed command make all duplicate column as single column as a pipe **"|"** separator.

**Solution tried:**

```
1.sed 's/"//g' SDC.TXT >  outout.TXT
2.sed 's/\t/","/g'  outout.TXT  > outout.csv
3.sed -i 's/.*/"&"/' outout.csv
```

These commands are used to convert text to csv by removing double quotes

But duplicate columns are getting as one string.How to make duplicate column as separate column header.

Attaching result get using this commands :
[Result after executing above commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd13e.png)

Attaching expected result :
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLRfm.png)

Comment: Don't expect readers to go to external sites to understand your problem. Include sample input and expected output directly in your Q. Use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on select text to get the correct formatting. ALSO, where is your attempted solution? Include your best attempt to solve your problem, and readers will help you understand why its not working. Good luck.

Comment: `sed command make all duplicate column as single column as a pipe "|" separator` Your sed commands do not do that at all. sed doesn't care about duplicated columns, it is not a csv reader. I'm not sure to understand the problem here. It looks like your txt file is already csv/dsv compliant. It uses `|` or `\t` (not sure because it is not clear on your post) and quotechars. You are trying to remove these quotechars (I cannot understand why because they are important). Your last sed command adds quote at the beginning and end of each line which basically will create one big column per line.

Comment: I don't know what kind of tool you use to read this file but you should rather configure and set delimiter to `|` and activate quotechars on this tool.